# Создание ПО с плагинами

Tags: c#, delphi, плагин, desktop, рефлексия

По долгу службы требуется реализация довольно сложного десктопного ПО. Как одно из требований — плагины (подключаемые модули), которые могут быть очень разнообразными: от определения новых типов данных до работы с интерфейсом (добавление форм, кнопок и т.п.). Разумеется, также требуются аналитика, обработка данных, сохранение в разные БД и т.д.

Платформы для выбора — C# или Delphi (т.к. есть прототип, реализующий 90% потребного функционала, но в режиме «спагетти»).

Если с Delphi всё понятно — средство загрузки/выгрузки плагинов делать руками, то вот с C# не всё так прозрачно.

Пока что быстрый поиск показал следующие варианты:

- [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/Dd460648(v=VS.110).aspx): довольно просто в реализации, но нельзя изолировать плагины в отдельных AppDomain (что довольно-таки важно, это существенное архитектурное преимущество .NET вообще и шарпа в частности);
- [MAF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200(v=vs.110).aspx): переусложнено, замудрённо, и, с виду, уже не поддерживается. С другой стороны — мощная изоляция;
- самостоятельная реализация на reflection (например, [так](http://habrahabr.ru/post/242209/)), с возможностью загрузки в AppDomain и прочим. Но придётся много велосипедить, чего в общем-то не хочется.

Есть ещё варианты? Может, что-то не было учтено?

**UPD**: добавил ссылки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для C# есть встроенное готовое решение от Microsoft: [System.Addin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Позволяет конфигурировать плагины так, чтобы использовать их в том же AppDomain'е, или в выделенном другом, или каждый в своём, или вообще в отдельном процессе.

Не понимаю, почему везде советуют MEF. Это решение именно для расширяемости: код, который вы загружаете, считается доверенным и очень мало отличается от основного кода приложения, поэтому возможности выгрузки и управление правами напрочь отсутствуют.

Самостоятельный велосипед на reflection написать можно, но придётся довольно серьёзно разбираться в тонкостях наподобие Fusion и Load context, так что я бы не советовал тратить время.

---

Обновление: Ага, `System.Addin` — это то, что вы называете MAF.

Comment: Именно так, [Managed Add-In Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200(v=vs.110).aspx). Проблема в том, что он очень монструозный и переусложнённый (ИМХО). Кроме того, я не очень понял, зачем ваять столько слоёв абстракции (правда, я его только один день внимательно читал).

Comment: @Norritt: На мой вкус, они нужны, если делать что-то нетривиальное. В любом случае, обвязочный код пишется один раз в жизни — вы ведь не собираетесь на _этом_ экономить? Это в любом случае быстрее, чем отлаживать баги в велосипеде.

Comment: Да, и ещё — подскажите, данный вид решения поддерживается сейчас? В интернетах на удивление мало примеров и статей на эту тему, [PipelineBuilder](https://vsgallery.com/62772a9c-11d8-43c1-83ed-cfb78a537274/view/Reviews) обновился, конечно, но как-то тоже не пестрит радостными отзывами. В общем, такое чувство, что [все пишут свои велосипеды](http://habrahabr.ru/post/242209/), и это несколько напрягает — значит, у System.AddIn «не получилось».

Comment: @Norritt: Ну, [говорят, что поддерживается](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1b43f0c4-e78b-4b72-aef7-0f715124ac19/is-systemaddin-still-alive-maf-managed-add-in-framework?forum=csharpgeneral).

Comment: @Norritt: Хабр такой хабр. Поллинг для проверки жизни плагина, о боже. Никогда не читайте его до обеда (ц).

Comment: я не спорю, велосипед там тот ещё выходит. Но волочь за собой помимо контракта ещё по два адаптера и представления (на стороне плагина и на стороне хоста), причём код дублируется внутри этих представлений, и, до кучи, ещё и абстрактные классы, которые де-факто дублируют контракт... Для одного-двух плагинов ещё куда ни шло, а для пары десятков? это ж будет монстр какой-то...

Comment: А, понял момент. Надо ещё немного подумать над структурой приложения :)

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от специфических требований к вашей системе. Так ли нужна изоляция в отдельный домен? Если код ваших плагинов не предполагает взаимодействия с Native библиотеками, то и исключения, выбрасываемые из плагина, не поломают вашу программу целиком. Вы вполне можете их перехватить, по стеку установить плагин-виновник и предложить пользователю в следующий раз не загружать его. Ну да, не так круто, как в динамике выгрузить домен, но зато насколько меньше возни. Вот Студия же работает именно так.
Ну а если ваши плагины способны нарушить работу процесса на уровне ОС, то ляжет весь процесс приложения вместе с CLR и доменами.

Поэтому с MAF я бы не связывался. Что до остального, могу посоветовать Mono.Addins. По возможностям превосходит MEF. Документация есть, но не исчерпывающая. Примеров маловато.
Также есть система `ICSharpCode.Core`, используемая в SharpDevelop, она тоже мощная, есть исходники (сам шарпдевелоп). Но документации почти нет, и она сильно устарела.

Comment: Злонамеренный плагин может нарушить работу основной программы через reflection, причём так, что юзер об этом не узнает. Грузить потенциально опасный код в свой AppDomain — не лучшая идея. Поэтому для плагинов, загружаемых из интернета или тому подобной модели нужно грузить в отдельный домен с урезанными правами.

Comment: Ну я ж говорю - зависит от требований. Автор не указывает, кто будет писать эти плагины, может, это будет доверенный источник.

Comment: И насколько мне кажется, злонамеренный/глючный плагин может-таки прибить основной процесс. Например, (случайно или намеренно) запустить бесконечный цикл в главном потоке или переполнить стек.

Comment: В общем да, хочется подложить соломку на случай некорректно реализованных плагинов (или, наоборот, целенаправленно ломающих родительский код, например, для целей нарушения лицензии). Кроме того, есть желание подстраховаться от получения доступа к данным, к которым этот доступ не хотелось бы давать всем и каждому. Устаревшее использовать особого желания нет, MS любит резать старые технологии...

Comment: А почему старые? Всё [поддерживается](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1b43f0c4-e78b-4b72-aef7-0f715124ac19/is-systemaddin-still-alive-maf-managed-add-in-framework?forum=csharpgeneral).

Comment: @Norritt: Кстати, если вы грузите злонамеренный плагин в свой процесс, но в другой AppDomain, не забудьте запретить ему unsafe-код и P/Invoke. Иначе он может легко выбраться в основной AppDomain.